# How can I extend an SQL query in a variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sql-injection

I am testing possible SQL injections on my DB, and I am running a simple function to get results which a user should not be getting. The return value is correct based on id, however, the rest of the query is completely being ignored.

I want to return all the data from the data table.

Is there something wrong in my syntax?

Here is my implementation:

```
function test(id) {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", [id], (err, result) => {
    console.log(result[0]);
  });
}

const id = "122 UNION SELECT * FROM data";
test(id);
```

Comment: The driver shouldn't allow you to inject SQL in ID.
It's not clear to me what API you are using but generally drivers will sanatize or precompile your statement before inserting values.
SQL injection generally happens when you manually concatenate.

Comment: Looks like a security hole in your language or API. **Do not concatenate parameters**, but use "prepared statements" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like nodejs Javascript with the [npm mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) driver package. And, I guess your `id` column is defined as an INT or BIGINT, not as some kind of text string.

The way you use the `.query()` method is the correct way to prevent SQL injection. It's parameterized. That means each parameter in the SQL is represented by a `?` placeholder. The second argument to `.query()` is an array of parameter values to substitute for the placeholders. For your use case the driver generates a query looking like this.

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '122 UNION SELECT * FROM data'
```

and passes it to the MySQL server. The server then takes the string you passed and attempts to interpret it as a number. Due to a quirk in MySQL, it interprets your `'122 UNION SELECT * FROM data'` string as the number 122, and so looks up `WHERE id = 122`.   (MySQL coerces strings to integers by looking for a leading number. So `123RedLight` gives 123, and `Hello` gives 0. It can be confusing. Other makes and models of RDBMS throw  errors when given strings where they expect integers.)

It correctly ignores the rest of your string.

If you wanted to make your code vulnerable to SQL injection (you do **not** want to do that!) you would write

```js
function test(id) {   /* danger: sql injection in next line */
  db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " + id, (err, result) => { /* wrong ! */
    console.log(result[0]);
  });
}
```

This would send

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 122 UNION SELECT * FROM data
```

to the server, and give you your data leak.

Comment: Why is SQL injection dangerous?  See https://haveibeenpwned.com/ for some hints.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and detailed explanation. Just learned a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it this way. In fact, not being able to do this is the **WHOLE POINT** of parameterized queries. It prevents an attacker from giving you a string like `122; DROP Table users;` as the input.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on what exactly parametrized is in your answer? Is it built-in? If so, then how are sql-injections possible?

Comment: It's also called "prepared statements", and most libraries (at least, those worth using) do have the capability built in. That SQL injections are **NOT** possible is the whole point. SQL injection happens when someone uses raw string concatenation instead of the parameterized query feature.